# WebSocket is closed immediately

Tags: javascript, c#, react-native, websocket, kestrel-http-server

When I open a WebSocket in React Native, it is closed immediately. There is no code or reason. It also receives an error which has no message. I am using WebSockets through an ngrok http tunnel. My server receives the request and completes the connection. If I send data immediately, it will be received, but about 1/4 of a second later, the connection is closed and I cannot send any data. I then receive an error server-side saying the connection was closed without completing the handshake. What am I doing wrong? This is on Android.

C# server code:

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) => {
                if (!context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("/notifications/")) {
                    await next();
                    return;
                }
                if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest) {
                    WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                } else {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                }
            });
```

JS Client Code:

```
import Defaults from "../Defaults";
import Services from "../Services";

export default class NotificationService {
    constructor(){
        this.socket = null;
    }

    subscribe(userId, onmessage){
        let url = Defaults.webRoot.replace('http', 'ws') + '/notifications/' + userId;
        this.socket = new WebSocket(url);
        this.socket.onmessage = onmessage;
        this.socket.onerror = this.onerror;
        this.socket.onclose = this.onclose;
        this.socket.onopen = this.onopen;
    }

    onerror(event){
        alert('ws error: ' + event.message);
    }

    onclose(event){
        alert('ws closed: ' + event.code + ' - ' + event.reason);
    }

    onopen(event){
        alert('ws opened');
    }
}
```

onclose shows `'ws closed: undefined - undefined'`.

I use the socket in a later request, but I have to assume the socket isn't just closed immediately once the request is completed, that would be stupid.

The state is `Open` by the time it gets to my code that sends messages. Yet it is obviously closed and does not receive messages on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If I complete the request, this for some reason also closes the web socket. There must be something coming back in the response that confuses the web socket, although I assumed the request and the socket itself would be two totally different things.

I basically have to add this line to keep the socket alive: `while (!webSocket.State.HasFlag(WebSocketState.Closed) && !webSocket.State.HasFlag(WebSocketState.Aborted)) {}`

I'm really not sure what that will do to performance and I'm concerned that I have to do that. I suppose you could make it slightly less terrible with a `Thread.Sleep` call in the while loop.

Hopefully, someone understands this problem better, and knows how to better fix the issue.

Comment: Nope sorry, I completely deleted this entire project years ago. I would assume in the `IsWebSocketRequest` block after web socket creation.